# Photoshop shortcut to select specific color swatches

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, shortcuts, swatches

Is there any shortcut to change brush tool color that I'm currently using from green swatch to red swatch?

I need to have several colors that I would change constantly using shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Record a new Action and click a swatch you want;
- Assign it to an F-key;
- Repeat for any number of swatches (well, until you have free F-keys with all the keyboard modifiers left);

[image]

Comment: Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Set one as foreground & the other as background, then swap using  <kbd>X</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but no, I know this one. I need to have several colors that I would change constantly.

Comment: Then you need to ask the question you require the answer to.

Comment: I've changed it.